# Best Regards or Best regards

Tags: differences

My Gmail suggests using the following

```
Best Regards
Jimmy Doe
```

I do not understand why "Regards" is capitalized in this case. Should it not be:

```
Best regards
James Doe
```

Answer (score 2):

Tastes vary. For example:

> [GrammarBook](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/effective-writing/hitting-the-right-notes-with-salutations-and-closings/)
>
> Closing personal written communication offers a wide range of phrasing and words depending on the type of relationship and the tone the writer wants to convey. Just a few include:
>
> *Keep smiling; Till we meet again; Yours truly; With love; Sincerely yours; Many thanks; Wishing you well*
> The first word is typically the only one capitalized in a personal closing; however, hard-and-fast rules do not govern this area.

Also, see:

> [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zv7fqp3/articles/zkq8hbk#z973vwx6)

> How you sign off will depend on how you started your letter. Here are the rules you must follow:
>
> If you used someone’s name at the start, end with ‘Yours sincerely,’
> If you used ‘Dear Sir or Madam’ instead, end with ‘Yours faithfully,’
> Again, whichever way you need to end your letter, it must be followed with a comma.

These examples agree with your own view and put my own experience into a minority: I have been brought up to use capitals this last 70 years in these valedictory phrases:
*Kind Regards, Yours Sincerely, Yours Faithfully, and so forth.*